# lack of smooth expand collapse of li elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide down li elements on mouseenter of ul and on mouseleave it will slideup its li elements. When I have varying number of li elements, when one slides up it automatically causes mouseenter on other ul

How can this be prevented to ensure a smooth expand/collapse experience?

This is what i have tried so far, i am using hovering variable to have a flag so that for next 2 seconds the mouseenter doesnt cause collapsing/expanding

```
var hovering=0;
$("ul").mouseenter(function (e) {
    console.log(hovering + " " +  Math.random());
    setTimeout(function(){
        clearHover();
    }, 1000);

    if (hovering == 0) {
        hovering = 1;
        $(this).children("li").slideDown();
        $(".nav").not(this).find("li").slideUp();
    }
});

$("ul").mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(this).children("li").slideUp();
    hovering = 0;
});

function clearHover(){
    hovering = 0;
    console.log(hovering + " " + Math.random());
};
```

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/52/)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.  When your mouse leaves to the right, there isn't much room for error because the elements extend all the way to the edge of the page.  Maybe some padding around those ul's will help?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that it automatically opens another ul, all your ul's are 100% width. No wonder you will hover over one of them when leaving another. Try adding this in the css:

```
ul {width: 50px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you display the ul as a table, you'll get a width that flexes with the content of the header text (where you have "1st", "2nd", etc.)

```
ul {display: table;}
```